Sending backup file via command line (headless Debian server with no GUI) offsite
I used to use mutt to email the redmine database to myself using an outlook account, but it no longer works due to some security changes they must have implemented last month. This is a headless Debian server that launches the backup command via cron, and there's no GUI, so most 2FA accounts don't work. Outlook worked for about a year until on September 29th it stopped working.
I'm looking for a simple way to automate sending the backup file, which is small and typically <10mb. The server does have internet access. What's a good way to do this? It should be somewhat secure in the sense that the server should keep the emails secure the same way you'd expect from ordinary email service providers.
All the infrastructure/code is already there to generate the backup file, zip it up, email it, and then delete the backup off of the local disk of the server. It's just that the email step is presently broken and I'm looking for a solution. Preferably one where I can include the password/username/credential in one line without having to mess around with mutt credential files. Any solution is acceptable, not just email. Uploading to secure cloud storage, etc...

If You are satisfied how everything worked, may be a new mail account is an option? You could get e.g. a Migadu account for $19/year and access it with web interface or any email client. You will have to get a domain if You don't have one and setup DNS records (this is one time setup though).

We don't want to pay for a solution.
